# Liquidgraph does not support bolt+routing in the url?

Tags: neo4j, liquigraph

I'm trying to use this liquidgraph tool to manage our schemas on neo4j and endup in a situation where to url below works

> jdbc:neo4j:bolt://neo4j:7687

but this one

> jdbc:neo4j:bolt+routing://neo4j:7687

I get

> ERROR com.hubrick.recommendation.Neo4JMigrationExecutor - Migration
>   failed error=java.sql.SQLException: JDBC URL is not correct.

Apparently from what I can see the neo4j driver that liquidgraph is using does not support routing yet?

routing for us is really important since we have cluster and without rounting it might happen that the migration will run in the FOLLOWER and not in the LEADER and then fail right away since it does not have writing access.

So is the any option to make it work?

Comment: Plus i guess neo4j team is not supporting this driver anymore https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc

Comment: it actually is more a neo4j drive issue rather than liquidgraph, I spoke with neo4j guys and they are about to release a new version of the driver which supports routing in the url

Comment: https://github.com/liquigraph/liquigraph/issues/210

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the neo4j driver didn't support routing yet, luckily a new version was on the way so basically for now just exclude the current driver from liquigraph project and import the version

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
>         <version>3.3.1</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

and routing will be supported.